# Linker error while trying to use assembler code in cpp module

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, assembly, nasm

I'm using visual studio 2013 and trying to run simple nasm code.

main.cpp:

```
#include "Header.h"
void _printf() {
    printf("HELLO\n");
}

int main()
{
    sayHello();
    return 0;
}
```

Header.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void _printf();

extern "C" {
    void sayHello();
}
```

and asm file hello.asm:

```
SECTION .text

EXTERN _printf

global sayHello
sayHello:
    push ebx
    call _printf
    pop ebx
ret
```

after that I get the following error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sayHello referenced in function _main    c:\Users\art.mhtr\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication8\ConsoleApplication8\main.obj    ConsoleApplication8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the error message you will see that the function it can not find is named `_sayHello`. Note the leading underscore.

To solve your problem you must name your assembler function with a leading underscore:

```
global _sayHello
_sayHello:
    ...
```

Comment: I still get an error in a runtime. Program just crashes

Comment: To call your `_printf` you need to use `call __printf`. Or, revert back to original code and use `nasm --prefix _`

Comment: It says that '__printf' is undefined

Comment: You also need to make your `_printf` as `extern C` otherwise its name will be c++ mangled.

Comment: @Artyom: I'd highly recommend using a less confusing name for your `_printf`.  From your asm code, I assumed you were trying to call the C standard library `printf` with garbage args.  (That's what happened, BTW, and why your program linked but then crashed.)

Comment: Worked, I was searching for this solution since last 4 hours, a big thank you.